# Draw a specific line into TikZ diagram when the x axis has an ordinary scale

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I created a pillar chart with TikZ. It has a percentage on the y-axis and an ordinary scale on the x-axis.

[image: the diagram as it is now]

I now calculated the average value by associating each ordinary value with an absolute value. How can I draw this average (as a vertical line) into the chart.

In the image, the average for the "original implementation" would be 1.875 which means I would like to draw a line between "low" and "low-medium".

Hear is my code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    ybar, 
    ylabel=in \%, 
    bar width=20pt, 
    symbolic x coords={low, low-medium, medium-high, high, very-high},
    xtick={low, low-medium, medium-high, high, very-high}, 
    x tick label style={rotate=45, anchor=east, align=center},
    height=8cm,
    width=15cm,
    title={Coupling amount per class classified with low, low-medium, medium-high, high, very-high},
    nodes near coords,         
    nodes near coords align={vertical}, ]
        \addplot[draw = brown, fill = brown] coordinates{(low,87.5) (low-medium,12.5) (medium-high,0) (high,0) (very-high,0)};
        \addplot[draw = orange, fill = orange] coordinates{(low,100) (low-medium,0) (medium-high,0) (high,0) (very-high,0)};
        
        \legend{original implementation, FP implementation}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please, next time, use a complete MWE --- so that we have a *compilable* snippet with all the packages etc. needed to run (see the example in my answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure I understand: if the `x` coordinates are `symbolic`, saying that `x=1.875` makes no sense: in symbolic coordinates, only the discrete values have a sense.

So you have two possibilities:

The first one is to use the `rel axis cs:` coordinate system inside the graphic. This is a coordinate system that starts from `(0,0)` at the bottom left and goes to `(1,1)` at the top right. You have to guess a bit the position, though... I added

```latex
\draw[thick, brown, dashed] (rel axis cs:{(1.875-0.5)/5},0) -- 
     (rel axis cs:{(1.875-0.5)/5},1);
```

[image]

The other one, if the values are really for example `1` for `low`, 2 for `low-medium` etc., you explicitly use a graph with the numerical x and then draw the line where you need with a draw:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    ybar,
    ylabel=in \%,
    bar width=20pt,
    xmin=0.5, xmax=5.5,
    xtick={1,...,5},
    xticklabels ={low, low-medium, medium-high, high, very-high},
    x tick label style={rotate=45, anchor=east, align=center},
    height=8cm,
    width=15cm,
    title={Coupling amount per class classified with low, low-medium, medium-high, high, very-high},
    nodes near coords,
    nodes near coords align={vertical}, ]
        \addplot[draw = brown, fill = brown] coordinates{(1,87.5) (2,12.5) (3,0) (4,0) (5,0)};
        \addplot[draw = orange, fill = orange] coordinates{(1,100) (2,0) (3,0) (4,0) (5,0)};
        \draw[thick, brown, dashed] (1.875,0) -- (1.875,100);
        \legend{original implementation, FP implementation}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your solution. The second approach you provided is the one I now use. I was not aware of the possibility to use the ordinal values while still using numerical values since it was my first time with tikzpicture.